# Linear Search using modified 2D array

Tags: java, loops

How do I fix the multiple prints of -1 in the last nested loop?  I'm making a linear search for 2D array but when the number is found the -1 prints multiple times even tho my condition is -1 when the number isn't found.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class FindInGroup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.print("Enter number of groups: ");
        int groups = scanner.nextInt(); //number of groups
        System.out.print("Enter number of elements to be search: ");
        int nSearch = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] elements = new int[groups][];
        for (int i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter number of elements for group %d: ", i + 1);
            elements[i] = new int[scanner.nextInt()];

            for (int j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("Enter value: ");
                elements[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        //print the array System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(elements));
        int[] search = new int[nSearch];
        for (int i = 0; i < nSearch; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number(s) to be search: ");
            search[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < groups; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < elements[j].length; k++) {
                    if (search[i] != elements[j][k]) {
                        System.out.println(-1);
                    }
                    else System.out.println("Found at group " + (j + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You check each element of your group against the number you are searching for, and print -1 if it isn't equal, so of course it prints more than once. You need to record whether you've found the number, and just check that flag at the end to decide what to print.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if (search[i] != elements[j][k]) {
    System.out.println(-1);
  }
else 
   System.out.println("Found at group " + (j + 1));
```

To this

```
if (search[i] == elements[j][k]) 
{    
  System.out.println("Found at group " + (j + 1));
  return;
}
```

You should only care when you have found the element and break it there so it doesn't proceed after that point

Finally at the end of your main method

```
  System.out.println("Element not found");
```

Which will be called only if your for loop didn't return i.e element was not found